# WSO2 API Manager(wso2am-3.2.0) 403 Forbidden Error When Adding a Secondary JDBC Userstore from Carbon Console

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are using wso2am-3.2.0(downloaded from Github) and the following error appears in the browser when creating a secondary jdbc userstore. The test connection option tells that the connection is healthy as well.

[image]

In the wso2carbon.log the following null pointer error appears.

```
TID: [-1] [] [2021-11-03 11:50:08,103] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve} - Could not handle request: null java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.internal.Utils.getTenantDomain(Utils.java:41)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.initCarbonContext(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:79)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any input to fix this issue is very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

- OS: Linux
- Database: MariaDB
- Userstore: JDBC

The changes made in the deployment.toml are as follows.

```
[server]
hostname = "<hostname>"
node_ip = "<ip>"
#offset=0
mode = "single" #single or ha
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "<new_password>"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

[database.apim_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://<ip>:3306/am_db"
username = "<username>"
password = "<password>"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://<ip>:3306/reg_db"
username = "<username>"
password = "<password>"
```

Comment: Did you change any default configurations? Can you add the configurations in `deployment.toml` file

Comment: @VithursaM added to the description.

Comment: `url = "jdbc:mysql://<ip>:3306/reg_db"` did you create a db called `reg_db`? By default the db scripts look for `shared_db`.

Comment: Yes I created a db by the name reg_db, ran the relavant db scripts as per documentation and pointed the shared_db to it.